# Server-side validation and form action

Tags: php, html, validation

I have a page (call it **form.php**) with a form for users to fill out. When the form is submitted, I want to validate it with a server-side script (call it **validate.php** if necessary, although the code could also go in one of the other pages if that would be better). If any part of the form fails validation, I want to kick back to **form.php** with the fields the user needs to fix highlighted. If the form passes validation, I want to go to another page, **success.php**.

Which page should I put in the "action" attribute of the `<form>` element, and what's the best way to get from that page to one of the others?

Comment: did you sort this out?  Any of our answers help?

Comment: As it turns out, even though I expected to need an answer right away when I asked the question, the other dev I'm working with still doesn't have the back-end script ready for me yet. I haven't forgotten about these answers and I intend to try them as soon as I can... thanks all for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of answers to this, it's a bit of a style thing.  I'd post `form.php` -> `form.php`.  If it passes validation then it can display the content of `success.php`, if it fails, it can show the same form again with the updated values.  If the updated URL is key to your application workflow, you could always use a URL redirection after validation is successful.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the action be form.php (same as the display page). In the PHP check if the request is a GET or a POST. If it is a GET simply display the blank form. If it's a POST validate the response, and if it is valid REDIRECT to success.php. If it is not valid render the form again (form.php) with the errors highlighted inline.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the approach used by Magento.

You have a formAction method in your controller that displays the form, then another action formPostAction that handles the form submission.

If the validation fails for example, you should create a proper error message, then store in the session an array with the form data just submitted and redirect to the form page.

The formAction() method should have a bit of logic to handle data in session, cleaning those once used for the output, to avoid security issues.